# PDO & MS SQL Server: inserting value for integer column results in error

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to insert an integer value into my INT column. However, when I execute the following PHP-code, it results in an error telling me that I am trying to insert a "text", which should not be the case...

**PHP**

```
$myCode = 1;
$sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tblCodes (myCode) VALUES (:myCode)");
$sth->bindParam(':myCode', $myCode, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification: 206
>   [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Operand type clash: text is incompatible with int
>   (SQLExecute[206] at
>   /builddir/build/BUILD/php-5.6.9/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:254)

Can anybody help me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show the value of  $code? Probably not a valid integer.

Comment: actually, your column is what's probably the incorrect type. could be either/or

Comment: @user_0 The value of $code is 1, as shown above.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've also tried to insert the value as "PARAM:STR", but that results in the same error.

Comment: uh....... `code` is a MySQL reserved word which should be wrapped in ticks `\`` - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html that's probably why and could be the same for sql server. Try that.

Comment: In practise, I don't use "code", but a non-reserved term. I replaced it to make it more accessible. Apparently confusing, I will edit. Sorry!

Comment: In the meantime, I double-checked my column's type, which is INT(4) NOT NULL.

Comment: You tried to bind `:code` to `:myCode`. You need to change one of those.

Comment: @JayBlanchard This was a mistake in my example code, not in my real code. Thanks though...

Comment: OK - just making sure we eliminate all of the variables.

Comment: @Mark may be a silly question but I'll ask it anyway; you are using PDO to connect with, yes?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, what do you mean by that? I am using PDO to connect to my MS SQL Server using ODBC, if that's of any help....

Comment: You may want to check again, this *seems* to be *partially fixed* in PHP 7. [While I can execute the statement once, I cannot seem to execute multiple times.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39088156/4233593)

Answer (score 0):

Such a situation may appear if the user to whom you connect to the database does not have the appropriate permissions.

A moment ago I had a similar problem with the scalar function. It turned out that adding execute permissions to the user solved the problem. Without permission, it seems to me that the driver is unable to determine the data types, and by default it assumes it is text.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it is a bug. I solved my problem by change in the query. In your case change the query as below:

```
$myCode = 1;
$sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tblCodes (myCode) VALUES (CAST(CAST(:myCode AS varchar) AS INTEGER))");
$sth->bindParam(':myCode', $myCode, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

Now it should be worked by both `PDO::PARAM_INT` and `PDO::PARAM_STR`.

Comment: Hi Mohammad - please do not add religious proselytism into your posts here, and if people remove non-essential material, please leave it like that. You may roll back if someone has changed the substantive meaning of your technical material. Thanks!