# Prepared statement cannot be executed multiple times with integer values

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, odbc, prepared-statement

How do I properly re-execute a prepared statement using different integer values?

There's something deathly wrong with explicit and implicit binding `PDO::PARAM_INT` when reusing an ODBC prepared statement.

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytab (
    col INT,
    something VARCHAR(20)
);
```

## Works : multiple strings

```
$pdoDB = new PDO('odbc:Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;
  Server='.DATABASE_SERVER.';
  Database='.DATABASE_NAME,
  DATABASE_USERNAME,
  DATABASE_PASSWORD
);
$pdoDB->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$values = ['here','are','some','values'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytab (something) VALUES (:something)";
$stmt = $pdoDB->prepare($sql);
foreach ($values as $value)
  $stmt->execute(['something'=>$value]);
```

## Works : single integer

```
$values = [42];
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytab (col) VALUES (:col)";
$stmt = $pdoDB->prepare($sql);
foreach ($values as $value)
  $stmt->execute(['col'=>$value]);
```

## Does Not Work : multiple integers

```
$values = [1,3,5,7,11];
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytab (col) VALUES (:col)";
$stmt = $pdoDB->prepare($sql);
foreach ($values as $value)
  $stmt->execute(['col'=>$value]);
```

It actually successfully inserts the first record `1` but fails when it tries to reuse the statement on the next execute.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification: 206 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Operand type clash: text is incompatible with int (SQLExecute[206] at /build/php7.0-lPMnpS/php7.0-7.0.8/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:260)

I'm connecting from 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 running PHP 7.0.8 using the [Microsoft® ODBC Driver 13 (Preview) for SQL Server®](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50419)

---

I have tried wrapping the whole thing in [`PDO::beginTransaction`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php) and [`PDO::commit`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php)

I've also tried using [`PDOStatement::bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) but it throws the exact same error.

## Works

```
$values = [1];
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytab (col) VALUES (:col)";
$stmt = $pdoDB->prepare($sql);
foreach ($values as $value){
  $stmt->bindParam('col', $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

## Does Not Work

```
$values = [1,2];
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytab (col) VALUES (:col)";
$stmt = $pdoDB->prepare($sql);
foreach ($values as $value){
  $stmt->bindParam('col', $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

I think it's interesting to note that I am getting the exact same error as this [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30712605/4233593) using PHP 5.6.9. However, they are not able to execute even one statement, so I'm wondering if there's been a partial patch considering the exact line throwing the error has moved from [`odbc_stmt.c:254`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-5.6.9/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c#L254) to [`odbc_stmt.c:260`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.0.8/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c#L260)

## Workaround

If I prepare the statement *inside* the loop, then **it works just fine.** But I've read that this is very inefficient and I should be able to reuse the statement. I'm particularly worried about using this with massive datasets. Is this OK? Is there something better that I can do?

```
$values = [1,3,5,7,9,11];
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytab (col) VALUES (:col)";
foreach ($values as $value){
  $stmt = $pdoDB->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute(['col'=>$value]);
}
```

Comment: No idea if it helps, but [line 260](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.0.8/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c#L260) is the same line of code that threw the error in the previous version of PHP

Comment: Does it work if the table only has a single int column?

Comment: @DavidG nope, I have tested that explicitly too.

Comment: Does it work if you bind outside the loop to some var, and then inside the loop only update the value of that var and call execute only?

Comment: Does it work, if you use `$stmt->execute(['col'=>intval($value]));` ?

Comment: @drews nope, but thanks

Answer (score -1):

In case of prepared statements you have to use `bindParam` outside of loop, usually.

1. `bindParam` is a single step
2. setting bound variables is a repeatable step (loop)
3. you have to run `execute` for each repetition

I guess, something like that would work:

```
$stmt = $pdoDB->prepare("INSERT INTO mytab (col, key) VALUES (:col, :key)");

// bind params (by reference)
$stmt->bindParams(":col", $col, PDO::PARAM_STR); //bind variable $col
$stmt->bindParams(":key", $key, PDO::PARAM_INT); //bind variable $key

$values = ['here','are','some','values'];
foreach ($values as $i => $value) {
    $col = $value; //set col
    $key = $i; //set key
    $stmt->execute();
}
```